# Button release after x seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I need a button that you can press once and it changes its state and appearance to pressed. After 1 seconds the pressed button should be released.

I tried doing that with ToggleButton and CheckBox. But this is not what I need.

EXAMPLE:
I press the Button. Color of a rectangle is changed. After 1 second the Button is released.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: The button should play a sound. If I use ToggleButton or CheckBox that sound is played twice, because the button is checked two times.

Comment: "they fire up a property" - they do _what_? During that period of time where it stays "pressed" - should it be enabled ( you can actively depress it with the mouse) ?

Comment: You have IsChecked property, when using CheckBox or ToggleButton. Im Binding this property.

Comment: You are going to need a DispatcherTimer to set the ToggleButton.IsChecked property back to false.

Answer (score 2):

Something I wanted to add: consider using Task instead of a Timer.  One the plus side, it means you don't have to clean up after a DispatchTimer and stop it; on the negative side, it means you need to use Invoke() on the GUI object instead of changing it directly (because it'll be running from the non-gui thread.)

Here's some simple code that just does a momentary button disable/enable to illustrate:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnTest.Enabled = false;
    Task t = new Task(async () =>  { await Task.Delay(2000); EnableButton(); });
    t.Start();
}
private void EnableButton()
{
    btnTest.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { btnTest.Enabled = true; });
}
```

EDIT: changed to use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep().

Comment: Don't tie up a thread-pool thread doing nothing but a Sleep. Use Task.Delay instead.

Comment: Changed as suggested

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a timer event with interval 1000 (1 second)?
Like you press the button, fire up the timer event and when 1 second passes release the button.

Comment: Your answer should include how to do the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to go back and use the ToggleButton, but reset it after 1 second. That is what it's for. Create a click event for your ToggleButton and the make a DispatcherTimer to handle the delayed toggle.

```
    //Reference
    using System.Windows.Timers;

    //Toggle Button Click Event
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button.IsChecked = true;

        //Create New DispatcherTimer
        DispatcherTimer dst = new DispatcherTimer();
        dst.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);  //Set Interval to 1 second.       
        dst.Tick += Dst_Tick;                   
        dst.Start(); //Start Timer  
    }

    //Timer Elapsed Event
    private void Dst_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer t = (DispatcherTimer)sender; //Grab the DispatcherTimer
        t.Stop(); //Stop the timer or it will keep looping
        button.IsChecked = false; //Reset the ToggleButton          
    }
```

Comment: Now if you register to `button.IsCheckedChanged` you'll still get two executions: One for unchecked to checked and one for checked to unchecked ...

Comment: Hi I just did't really change the question. Just added some clarifications... 
I already implemented this solution. The problem with this is that IsChecked is pressing the button twice. For that reason a sound (the button should play a sound) is played twice.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a test application with your requirement.
my Xaml file looks like following

```
<Window x:Class="toggleButtonTimer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:toggleButtonTimer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_value"></TextBlock>
        <ToggleButton Width="100" Height="100" x:Name="_toggle" Click="_toggle_Click" IsChecked="False"></ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind is as follows (modified the code from Tronald..)

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
 ....


    private int value = 0;
    private void _toggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _toggle.IsChecked = true;

        //Create New DispatcherTimer
        DispatcherTimer dst = new DispatcherTimer();
        dst.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);  //Set Interval to 1 second.       
        dst.Tick += Dst_Tick;
        dst.Start(); //Start Timer  

        value++;
        _value.Text = value.ToString();
    }

    //Timer Elapsed Event
    private void Dst_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer t = (DispatcherTimer)sender; //Grab the DispatcherTimer
        t.Stop(); //Stop the timer or it will keep looping
        _toggle.IsChecked = false; //Reset the ToggleButton    

        value--;
        _value.Text = value.ToString();
    }
```

The TextBlock counts +1 the variable everytime click is fired and when the timer elapses, it counts -1. So the textBlock stays 0 after a cycle. This works fine for me. Because the result at the end is 0. So the event is processed only once.

It worked both for  **Click** event and the **Checked** event.